# Unfortunately MyApp has stop working when some listview item click

Tags: java, android

I am new in android. I have been developing a simple App. I have listview that contain 50 items. It's working when i click some top items. But when i scroll down the item and click some bottom item, it gives error "unfortunately myapp has stop working". 
I used switch case on listview item click.

can you give me how to solve this problem.?

Comment: Give us some error information, stacktrace, etc. We have nothing to go off of...

Comment: post adapter code and error log.

Comment: The app has run well. and it can build successfully. there is no error log. But when i run on my device, i scroll down the listview items and clicked.. it just gives an error "unfortunately app has stop working". i don't know that's why

Answer (score 0):

Although you havent given us any code or stack trace, hence it is pretty difficult to gauge what you are running into. But you can check whether you have handled for onclick of items after a certain range (When it fails). As you have stated that you are using switch case for the item click.